# Approximate roots of a cubic

Tags: polynomials

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be positive numbers.  Consider the cubic equation $x^2(ax+b) = c$.  Are there any useful bounds (upper and lower) I can put on the unique root of this equation for $x>0$?  For example, we know that $x^* <(c/a)^{1/3}$ and $x^* < \sqrt{c/b}$.  This equation can be solved explicitly, but that expression is rather complicated and I'm just looking to find an interval that contains a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the bounds you have?

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be $x^*<(c/a)^{1/3}$ - just lose the positive $x^2 b$ term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, since your $f(x):=x^2(ax+b)-c$ is convex on $[0,+\infty)$ the [Newton's iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_method) with initial point $x_0>0$ produces a sequence $x_n$ which is decreasing for $n\ge1$ and converges to $x^*$. 
From the equation, $y_n:=c/ax_n^2\, -\, b/a$ also converges to $x^*$, but increasing. This gives you an interval $[y_n, x_n]$  whose endpoints are rational functions of the coefficients (and as small as you wish, for large enough $n$).

Comment: The initial point for Newton's iteration should be $>0$, since $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: right! fixed    .